# Pipe Async - Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed

Tags: angular

I was using the Tour Heroes tutorial: https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6#search-by-name to create my own search bar. However the diff '[object Object]' error appeared and although lots of answers say that I need to convert the object in array form, in the tutorial, it says the async pipe take cares of that for me so i don't have to subscribe.

Thank you in advance!

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMQLy.jpg)

offer-search.component.html

```
    <input #searchBox id="search-box" (keyup)="search(searchBox.value)" />

      <ul class="search-result">
        <li *ngFor="let offer of offers$ | async" >
            {{offer.name}}
        </li>
```

offer-search.component.ts

```
...
import { Offer } from '../model/offer';
import { OfferService } from '../offer.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-offer-search',
  templateUrl: './offer-search.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./offer-search.component.css']
})
export class OfferSearchComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input('offerP') offerProperty: string;

  offers$: Observable<Offer[]>;
  private searchTerms = new Subject<string>();

  constructor(private offerService: OfferService) {}

  // Push a search term into the observable stream.
  search(term: string): void {
    this.searchTerms.next(term);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.offers$ = this.searchTerms.pipe(
      // wait 300ms after each keystroke before considering the term
      debounceTime(300),

      // ignore new term if same as previous term
      distinctUntilChanged(),

      // switch to new search observable each time the term changes
      switchMap((term: string) => this.offerService.searchOffersByProperty(term, this.offerProperty)),
    );
  }
}
```

offer.service.ts

```
...
  searchOffersByProperty(term: string, prpty: string): Observable<Offer[]> {
    if (!term.trim()) {
      // if not search term, return empty hero array.
      return of([]);
    }
    let searchURL = this.url + `/offers/?foodOfferer=${this.authService.credential.foodOfferer.id}&${prpty}=${term}`;
    return this.http.get<any>(searchURL, {
      headers: this.headers,
      responseType: 'json',
    }).pipe(catchError(this.handleError('searchOffersByProperty', '')));
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the docs state

> The AsyncPipe subscribes to an Observable automatically so you won't have to do so in the component class.

which means you don't have to manually subscribe in your component. Manually subscribing would look something like

```
// ts
this.searchTerms.pipe(
  debounceTime(300),
  distinctUntilChanged(),
  switchMap((term: string) => 
      this.offerService.searchOffersByProperty(term, this.offerProperty)),
  )
  .subscribe(offers => this.offers = offers);

// html
<li *ngFor="let offer of offers">
  {{offer.name}}
</li>
```

---

The async pipe does not do data transformation. For this you need to convert the result from your api (currently an object) to an array using the rxjs [map](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/map.html) method.

```
// ts
this.offers$ = this.searchTerms.pipe(
  debounceTime(300),
  distinctUntilChanged(),
  switchMap((term: string) => this.offerService.searchOffersByProperty(term, this.offerProperty)),
  map(results => {
      // do transformation here
      let resultsArray = ...;
      return resultsArray;
  })
);
```

Comment: I am not sure how would map give me an `Observable<Offer[]>` as it is used to change the values of the Observable<Object>. I tried this: `map(res => 
       {
        let resultsArray : Offer[];
        if(Array.isArray(res)){
         resultsArray = res;
        }
        return resultsArray;}
       )` but nothing is displayed.

Comment: @CCSJ map gives you `Observable<Offer[]>` because you are transforming your res to type `Offer[]`.  From your answer it seems the array is under the results property. So you need to return `.map(res => res.results)`

Comment: Thanks, it only works if i do that in offer.service.ts which has `import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';` But it didn't work in my component file because its using `import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';` I think.

Comment: I think I now understand `map()`. In the link you gave me, the Observable has multiple values. But in my case, the Observable only has 1 object which contains an array. Initially I was thinking the get request returns an observable containing multiple objects of the JSON file but it is returning an observable containing 1 object that has multiple objects.

Answer (score 0):

1. Found out `Offers$` is a `Observable<Object>` which contains the `Offer[]`, not `Observable<Offer[]>`
2. Found out that you need `?` if you are trying to access asynchronous variables
   so instead of :

`<li *ngFor="let offer of offers$ | async" >`

it is

`<li *ngFor="let offer of (offers$ | async)?.results" >`