# *ngFor loop over mLab objects produce Error trying to diff'[object Object] even after declaring array

Tags: node.js, angular, mlab

I have an array declared as `carousels: any = []` in my TS file but I keep getting an error stating 'only arrays and iterables allowed' whenever I loop over it using *ngFor. The data inside this array is acquired from mLab.

The goal of my code is to update an object from mLab using its id which seems to work fine. But whenever I press the update, given the fact that the update even works, why do I still get the error?

I have tried to change `carousels: any = []` to just `carousels = []` but it doesn't seem to change anything.

This is my code.

***api.js (backend)*** - this is the code that communicates with the database.

```
router.route('carousel/update/:_id).put(function(req, res) {

db.collection('home').updateOne({"_id": ObjectId(req.params._id)}, {$set: req.body}, (err, results) => {
if (err) throw err;
res.send(results)
console.log(req.params._id)
});
});
```

***home.service.ts***

```
return this.http.put<any[]>('./api/carousel/update/' + id, {'header': newheader, 'subheader': newsubheader})
}
```

***component.ts***

declaration:

```
carousels: any = [];
```

update function:

```
updateSlide(id: number){
this.HomeService.updateSlide(id, this.header, this.subheader).subscribe(slides => {this.carousels = slides})
}
```

Update works but I still get the Error: error trying to diff '[object object]'. only arrays and iterables are allowed

Comment: Did you try to convert your data to array?

Comment: @M98 by declaring the var carousels into an array, haven't I already converted my data into one? I'm a novice with angular so please bear with me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **.updateOne({})** doesn't return a list of objects, but an object with the information about the row updated.

You are returning that Object from the API and then setting it in the updateSlider() in your component, where you should be setting an array instead.

Try to log the *results* in the api or *slides* in the Subscription, and you should be able to see the issue.

Comment: Hi @Nayak. You're right, it definitely returns an object containing information about the row updated. How then do I modify my code to set it to an array instead?

Answer (score 0):

After several readings and posts, I have found out that my mistake was tha I manually subscribed to the Observable inside my component file.

Manually updating looks like this:

```
.subscribe(slides => {this.carousels = slides})
```

It turns out that this has already been done automatically therefore I would not need to do it again manually. Refer to this post: [Pipe Async - Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48391261/pipe-async-error-trying-to-diff-object-object-only-arrays-and-iterables-a)

This fixed the issue for me.